# Cursors stays where I click in VS text editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Sorry for question but I can't find answer anywhere on internet. I couldn't find answer myself either. Here is question:

Previously when I clicked anywhere in VS text editor cursor moved to the end of statement, just after ";". But now it stays where I click on the screen and it is really annoying. How can I address this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is called **Virtual Space** and can be changed in Visual Studio's options dialog.

As per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165328(v=vs.100).aspx) article:

> To position comments beside your code
>
> - In the Options dialog box, expand Text Editor, and then click the
>     General node for your development language.
> - Under Settings, select Enable virtual space.
>
> When this option is selected and Word wrap is cleared, you can click
>   anywhere beyond the end of a line in the Code Editor and type.

To revert to the behaviour you're after, you need to **uncheck** *Enable virtual space* either at the language level or for all languages:

[image: Visual Studio options dialog showing unchecked virtual space setting]

Also more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z01zks9a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you @Crispalot, I was about to get crazy. It addressed my problem. I will mark as answer after 7 minutes )

Comment: Thanks! I was going crazy too. I must have clicked this accidentally.

Comment: Or you can click on 'All languages' on the left which would open the same modal and unselect 'Enable virtual spacing'. This works too.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, you must check the `Tools - Options -Text Editor - All Languages - Scroll Bars` then check the `Show caret position` option.

[image]